# Laravel 5.4 - Get user data without log-in (for API)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to get user data

I tried using

```
$user_data = App\User::where(["username"=>"admin", "password"=>bcrypt("test123")])->get();
```

But it is not working! I am sure the username and password is correct!

then I tried another one without `bcrypt`

```
$user_data = App\User::where(["username"=>"admin", "password"=>"test123"])->get();
```

And still not working!.
I don't know what is the problem.

I wondering if I can use `Auth::attempt` just to get the user data (without log-in)

```
$user_data = Auth::attempt(["username"=>"admin", "password"=>"test123"]);
```

`Auth::attempt` will signing you in. But I don't want that. I just want to get the user data only (without sign-in)

Comment: What do you mean with not working? What do you get back?

Comment: i means it will return blank array... it should return me an array with a single data..

Comment: use JWT to authenticate (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I'm creating an API...

However, I solved the problem by using `Auth::once()`

```
Auth::once(['username'=>'admin', 'password'=>'test123']);
```

[image]